# How to find duplicate values and then update a field in the one table using sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

**Table Name:**
Tp

**Columns:**
TpId | PId | TId

How can I update TId column to the value of 3 for every row where PId is duplicated.

Comment: Sample data and expected results will make this far easier to answer; we have very little to go on as it is. What have you tried so far to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With EXISTS:

```
update  t
set tid = 3
from tp t
where exists (
  select 1 from tp
  where tpid <> t.tpid and pid = t.pid
)
```

I guess that `tpid` is unique in your table.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c23cb50f0e4a851d939ddf2ec6db137b).
If you want to update only all the duplicated rows except the first, then:

```
update t
set tid = 3
from tp t
where exists (
  select 1 from tp
  where tpid < t.tpid and pid = t.pid
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a8049880e707451fd972cf0508b68677).

Answer (score 1):

you can use `row_number()`

```
with cte as
(
select *,row_number()over(partition by PId order by TpId ) rn
from Tp
) update cte
  set  TId=3
  where rn=1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to update **all** rows where Pid is duplicated you can use something like this:

```
update Tp set Tid=3 where Pid in
(
  select Pid
  from Tp
  group by Pid
  having COUNT(*) > 1
)
```